# Speed up PowerShell script for Windows Registry search (currently 30 minutes)

Tags: performance, powershell, foreach, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm working on a script for use in Windows 7 and Windows 10 for a Windows Registry search in HKLM:\Software\Classes. So far my code works, but it's extremely slow. It takes about 30 minutes to complete.

I need to use [Set-Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location) also to avoid an error with Get-ItemProperty, which occurs because the $path is not a valid object.

How can I speed this code up? What's wrong?

#### File `regsearch.ps1` ([Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221709/speed-up-powershell-script-for-windows-registry-search-currently-30-minutes/39223168#39223168) applied)

```
Function Get-RegItems
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$path,
        [string]$match)

    #Set Local Path and ignore wildcard (literalpath)
    Set-Location -literalpath $path
    $d = Get-Item -literalpath $path

    # If more than one value -> process
    If ($d.Valuecount -gt 0) {
        $d |
        # Get unkown property
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property |
            ForEach {
                $val = (Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name $_).$_
                #if Filter $match found, generate ReturnObject
                if (($_ -match $match) -or ($val -match $match ) -or ($path-match $match)) {
                    New-Object psobject -Property @{ “key”=$path; “property”=$_; “value” = $val ;}
                }
            }
    }
} #end function Get-RegItems

Function RegSearch
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$path,
        [string]$match)

    # Expand $path if necessary to get a valid object
    if ($path.Indexof("HKEY") -ne "-1" -and $path.Indexof("Registry::") -eq "-1" )  {
        $path = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::" +$path
    }

    # Retrieve items of the main key
    Get-RegItems -path $path -match $match

    # Retrieve items of all child keys
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        ForEach {
            Get-RegItems -path $_.PsPath -match $match
        }
} #end function RegSearch


#$search = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office"
$searchkey = ‘HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\’
#$searchkey = "HKLM:\Software\Classes\"
$pattern = "EventSystem"

cls
$result = @()

Measure-Command {$result = Regsearch -path $searchkey -match $pattern }

# TESTING
#$t = @( "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes",
#       "HKLM:\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\",
#       "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\",
#       "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office")
#cls
#$t |ForEach { Get-RegItems -path $_ } | fl

if ($result.Count) {
    $result
    "Count: {0}" -f ($result.Count-1)
}
else {
    "Path: {0} `nNo Items found" -f $searchkey
}
```

Comment: Executing the Windows command line `reg` utility is the fastest solution. It doesn't support regexp-matching though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I accepted the challenge and made it "as fast as possible".
Now it is even faster than REGEDIT or any other tool.
The below sample lasts 11 seconds to parse the complete OFFICE-key and all subkeys.

In addition, it also searches for string-matches in REG-BINARY etc.

Enjoy!

```
# carsten.giese@googlemail.com
# reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vstudio/ms724875(v=vs.80)

cls
remove-variable * -ea 0
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

$signature = @'
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 RegOpenKeyEx(
    UInt32 hkey,
    StringBuilder lpSubKey,
    int ulOptions,
    int samDesired,
    out IntPtr phkResult
    );

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 RegQueryInfoKey(
    IntPtr hKey,
    StringBuilder lpClass, Int32 lpCls, Int32 spare, 
    out int subkeys, out int skLen, int mcLen, out int values,
    out int vNLen, out int mvLen, int secDesc,                
    out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime
);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern Int32 RegEnumValue(
  IntPtr hKey,
  int dwIndex,
  IntPtr lpValueName,
  ref IntPtr lpcchValueName,
  IntPtr lpReserved,
  out IntPtr lpType,
  IntPtr lpData,
  ref int lpcbData
);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern Int32 RegEnumKeyEx(
  IntPtr hKey,
  int dwIndex,
  IntPtr lpName,
  ref int lpcName,
  IntPtr lpReserved,
  IntPtr lpClass,
  int lpcClass,
  out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime
);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 RegCloseKey(IntPtr hkey);
'@ 
$reg = add-type $signature -Name reg -Using System.Text -PassThru
$marshal = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]

function search-RegistryTree($path) {

    # open the key:
    [IntPtr]$hkey = 0
    $result = $reg::RegOpenKeyEx($global:hive, $path, 0, 25,[ref]$hkey)
    if ($result -eq 0) {

        # get details of the key:
        $subKeyCount  = 0
        $maxSubKeyLen = 0
        $valueCount   = 0
        $maxNameLen   = 0
        $maxValueLen  = 0
        $time = $global:time
        $result = $reg::RegQueryInfoKey($hkey,$null,0,0,[ref]$subKeyCount,[ref]$maxSubKeyLen,0,[ref]$valueCount,[ref]$maxNameLen,[ref]$maxValueLen,0,[ref]$time)
        if ($result -eq 0) {
           $maxSubkeyLen += $maxSubkeyLen+1
           $maxNameLen   += $maxNameLen  +1
           $maxValueLen  += $maxValueLen +1
        }

        # enumerate the values:
        if ($valueCount -gt 0) {
            $type = [IntPtr]0
            $pName  = $marshal::AllocHGlobal($maxNameLen)
            $pValue = $marshal::AllocHGlobal($maxValueLen)
            foreach ($index in 0..($valueCount-1)) {
                $nameLen  = $maxNameLen
                $valueLen = $maxValueLen
                $result = $reg::RegEnumValue($hkey, $index, $pName, [ref]$nameLen, 0, [ref]$type, $pValue, [ref]$valueLen)
                if ($result -eq 0) {
                    $name = $marshal::PtrToStringUni($pName)
                    $value = switch ($type) {
                        1 {$marshal::PtrToStringUni($pValue)}
                        2 {$marshal::PtrToStringUni($pValue)}
                        3 {$b = [byte[]]::new($valueLen)
                           $marshal::Copy($pValue,$b,0,$valueLen)
                           if ($b[1] -eq 0 -and $b[-1] -eq 0 -and $b[0] -ne 0) {
                                [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($b)
                           } else {
                                [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($b)}
                           }
                        4 {$marshal::ReadInt32($pValue)}
                        7 {$b = [byte[]]::new($valueLen)
                           $marshal::Copy($pValue,$b,0,$valueLen)
                           $msz = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($b)
                           $msz.TrimEnd(0).split(0)}
                       11 {$marshal::ReadInt64($pValue)}
                    }
                    if ($name -match $global:search) {
                        write-host "$path\$name : $value"
                        $global:hits++
                    } elseif ($value -match $global:search) {
                        write-host "$path\$name : $value"
                        $global:hits++
                    }
                }
            }
            $marshal::FreeHGlobal($pName)
            $marshal::FreeHGlobal($pValue)
        }

        # enumerate the subkeys:
        if ($subkeyCount -gt 0) {
            $subKeyList = @()
            $pName = $marshal::AllocHGlobal($maxSubkeyLen)
            $subkeyList = foreach ($index in 0..($subkeyCount-1)) {
                $nameLen = $maxSubkeyLen
                $result = $reg::RegEnumKeyEx($hkey, $index, $pName, [ref]$nameLen,0,0,0, [ref]$time)
                if ($result -eq 0) {
                    $marshal::PtrToStringUni($pName)
                }
            }
            $marshal::FreeHGlobal($pName)
        }

        # close:
        $result = $reg::RegCloseKey($hkey)

        # get Tree-Size from each subkey:
        $subKeyValueCount = 0
        if ($subkeyCount -gt 0) {
            foreach ($subkey in $subkeyList) {
                $subKeyValueCount += search-RegistryTree "$path\$subkey"
            }
        }
        return ($valueCount+$subKeyValueCount)
    }
}

$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
$timer.Start()

# setting global variables:
$search = "enterprise"
$hive   = [uint32]"0x80000002" #HKLM
$subkey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office"
$time   = New-Object System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
$hits   = 0

write-host "We start searching for pattern '$search' in Registry-Path '$subkey' ...`n"
$count = search-RegistryTree $subkey

$timer.stop()
$sec = [int](100 * $timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)/100
write-host "`nWe checked $count reg-values in $sec seconds. Number of hits = $hits."
```

Answer (score 0):

The single biggest improvement you can make here is changing:

```
Set-Location -literalpath $path 
$d= Get-Item .
```

to

```
$d = Get-Item -LiteralPath $path
```

Manipulating the location stack for each key in the hierarchy introduces *A LOT* of unnecessary overhead

Comment: This is usefull, but results in an error with "(Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name $_).$_" when Set-Location is not used.. What works here is to set both: Set-Location -literalpath $path and $d = Get-Item -LiteralPath $path.. This is still not optimal..

Comment: Change to `Get-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $_` then

Comment: Get-ItemProperty : Property CodeBase does not exist at path 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\record\{FF9D9EF1-7F3E-4178-81CC-71CA06D58BFD}\15.0.0.0.
At C:\temp\regsearch.ps1:18 char:15
+       $val = (Get-ItemProperty -Path . -Name $_).$_
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CodeBase:String) [Get-ItemProperty], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyComm 
   and

Comment: @biohell see my other comment

Comment: To avoid the Error above, i changed to `Set-Location -literalpath $path
$d= Get-Item  -literalpath $path`

This seesm to works..

Answer (score 0):

**User function call overhead** (scriptblocks included) is extremely big (e.g. 0.1-1ms). This becomes a very serious issue when the function is executed thousands/millions of times. Surprisingly, it's not mentioned in optimization-related articles (at least I've never seen it and I googled this topic a lot).

Unfortunately, the only only real solution to this particular issue is to inline the code at the cost of duplication and reduced readability.

**Optimization should include code profiling.**
PowerShell doesn't have a code profiler so you'll need to do it manually with Measure-Command.
Use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch inside loops to display the accumulated time:

```
# global stopwatch
$sw1 = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
$sw2 = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
............
forEach(....) {
    ........
    $sw1.start()
    ........
    $sw1.stop()
    ........
    $sw2.start()
    ........
    $sw2.stop()
    ........
}
............
echo $sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds, $sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

Comment: It's not mentioned because best practice in function/cmdlet design would lead you to accept multiple inputs and only call the function once

Comment: i will give a try and see

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, accepting multiple inputs won't help in case the cmdlet or user function calls subfunction(s) for each item to process a verrrry long input array. I guess the problem is not mentioned because PowerShell scripts aren't supposed to be used in time-critical scenarios.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, is there an other approch to solve that performance problem ? Any suggetions  to improve perfomance ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a faster version of you sample-script.
Lasts ca. 1 minute on my machine.
If you need it faster, then you need to work with advapi32.dll-Pinvokes, but then
it will end quite complex.

```
Function Get-RegItems {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$path,
        [string]$match
    )
    #write-host $path.Substring(30)
    $key = Get-Item -literalpath $path
    ForEach ($entry in $key.Property) {
        $value = $key.GetValue($entry)
        if (($entry -match $match) -or ($value -match $match ) -or ($path -match $match)) { 
            write-host "key=$path property=$entry value=$value"
        }
    }
}

Function RegSearch {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$path,
        [string]$match
    )
    Get-RegItems -path $path -match $match
    ForEach ($item in get-ChildItem -literalpath $path -ea 0) {
        RegSearch -path $item.PsPath -match $match 
    }
}

cls
Remove-Variable * -ea 0
[System.GC]::Collect()

$searchkey =‘HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office’ 
$pattern = "EventSystem"
measure-command {
    $result = RegSearch -path $searchkey -match $pattern
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the registry drive provider, if you want it faster.

I've also read classes with static methods are faster.