# Powershell and Registry: How do I query for (Default| strings by their value instead of name?

Tags: powershell, registry

So, I have a script I'm working on to get items in the registry and delete them, like so:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes" -Recurse -Include *optane* | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force`

Now, I've got an issue where the registry values (say, *optane*) are in the value of the string, but the string itself is named (Default). I have no problems querying for a string itself, but when it's listed as default, I (of course) get no results. How do I query to get results by the value of the string instead of the name of the string?

[[image: Sample Registry Entry]]

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure of the syntax. Note that in this case, I'm trying to do it this way because I want to actually remove the GUID folder containing the item without having to find the GUID itself. I have pretty specific options I can use to keep it from being dangerous.

EDIT: after playing around with some of the code, I tried this so I could get the fieldnames and properties:

<Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCR:\CLSID{A3AF6F6C-8BED-3D93-8B5D-33427B5D38E9}">

and got the following response:

[image]

This tells me that I'd be good with getting any ProgId that contanes "Intel.Optane.Pinning" in its properties. I want to query for any ProgID containing that value, then delete the key that contains that value.

Comment: Use WHERE : Get-ChildItem -Path "*" -Recurse | Where-Object -Value -like `"*optane*"` | Remove-Item

Comment: I get an error (and note, I didn't forget New-PSDrive for HKCR):  Where-Object : Missing an argument for parameter 'Value'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Object' and try again.
At line:1 char:59
+ ... -ChildItem -Path "HKCR:\CLSID" -Recurse | Where-Object -Value -like " ...
+                                                            ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: I made a mistake and added WHERE :  in front (did not before), but get another error: Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Path'.
At line:1 char:23
+ WHERE : Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCR:\CLSID" -Recurse | Where-Object -Va ...
+                       ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

Comment: Should be HKCU See  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-keys?view=powershell-7.3#listing-all-subkeys-of-a-registry-key

Comment: See my edit. HKCR is what I really believe I'm looking for here.

Comment: Try following : Get-ChildItem -Path Registry::HKCU\CLSID -Recurse

Answer (score 0):

To search by value you'll have to get all keys/subkeys in your specified path first. Once you get the keys you'll have to go through each one and get the key values and data. The whole key (and subkeys) well be removed if any of it's value data contain the specified search term.

```
$searchRegKeyValue = "*test123*"
$myPath = "REGISTRY::HKCR\"
# $mypath = "REGISTRY::HKLM:\Software\"
$childItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $myPath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# go through each key in the reg path specified
foreach ($key in $childItems){
    # for each value of the key get it's value and compare against the search term
    foreach ($name in $key.GetValueNames()){
        if ($key.GetValue($name) -like $searchRegKeyValue){       
            # Get-Item -Path $key.pspath
            Remove-Item -Path $key.pspath -Recurse -WhatIf
        }
    }
}
```

The above solution works well if there are not a lot of keys/subkeys to go through but can get slow especially if you specify a top level path (`"REGISTRY::HKCR\" vs "REGISTRY::HKCR\CLSID"`).

I found a really interesting solution to speed up registry search in powershell [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55853204/20473839). So I modified the solution a bit to work with this use case. The speed up using this solution is more noticeable with a larger search set. I saw 50%+ speedup on the larger search set but on smaller it was closer. For my orginal solution it took 293 seconds to search HKCR:\ while using the solution linked it took 101 seconds.
[image]

Bellow is from the linked solution modified to remove the keys that have values that match `$search`. I had to change some things around in the search to account for an empty `$subKey` to search from root level but it's mostly the same other than that.

```
# carsten.giese@googlemail.com
# reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vstudio/ms724875(v=vs.80)

cls
remove-variable * -ea 0
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"

$signature = @'
[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 RegOpenKeyEx(
    UInt32 hkey,
    StringBuilder lpSubKey,
    int ulOptions,
    int samDesired,
    out IntPtr phkResult
    );

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 RegQueryInfoKey(
    IntPtr hKey,
    StringBuilder lpClass, Int32 lpCls, Int32 spare, 
    out int subkeys, out int skLen, int mcLen, out int values,
    out int vNLen, out int mvLen, int secDesc,                
    out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime
);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern Int32 RegEnumValue(
  IntPtr hKey,
  int dwIndex,
  IntPtr lpValueName,
  ref IntPtr lpcchValueName,
  IntPtr lpReserved,
  out IntPtr lpType,
  IntPtr lpData,
  ref int lpcbData
);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern Int32 RegEnumKeyEx(
  IntPtr hKey,
  int dwIndex,
  IntPtr lpName,
  ref int lpcName,
  IntPtr lpReserved,
  IntPtr lpClass,
  int lpcClass,
  out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime
);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 RegCloseKey(IntPtr hkey);
'@ 
$reg = add-type $signature -Name reg -Using System.Text -PassThru
$marshal = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]

function search-RegistryTree($path) {
    if(($path -ne "") -and !($path.EndsWith("\"))){
        $path +=  "\"
 
    }


    # open the key:
    [IntPtr]$hkey = 0
    $result = $reg::RegOpenKeyEx($global:hive, $path, 0, 25 ,[ref]$hkey)
    if ($result -eq 0) {

        # get details of the key:
        $subKeyCount  = 0
        $maxSubKeyLen = 0
        $valueCount   = 0
        $maxNameLen   = 0
        $maxValueLen  = 0
        $time = $global:time
        $result = $reg::RegQueryInfoKey($hkey,$null,0,0,[ref]$subKeyCount,[ref]$maxSubKeyLen,0,[ref]$valueCount,[ref]$maxNameLen,[ref]$maxValueLen,0,[ref]$time)
        if ($result -eq 0) {
           $maxSubkeyLen += $maxSubkeyLen+1
           $maxNameLen   += $maxNameLen  +1
           $maxValueLen  += $maxValueLen +1
        }

        # enumerate the values:
        if ($valueCount -gt 0) {
            $type = [IntPtr]0
            $pName  = $marshal::AllocHGlobal($maxNameLen)
            $pValue = $marshal::AllocHGlobal($maxValueLen)
            
            foreach ($index in 0..($valueCount-1)) {
                $nameLen  = $maxNameLen
                $valueLen = $maxValueLen
                $result = $reg::RegEnumValue($hkey, $index, $pName, [ref]$nameLen, 0, [ref]$type, $pValue, [ref]$valueLen)
                if ($result -eq 0) {
                    $name = $marshal::PtrToStringUni($pName)
                    $value = switch ($type) {
                        1 {$marshal::PtrToStringUni($pValue)}
                        2 {$marshal::PtrToStringUni($pValue)}
                        3 {$b = [byte[]]::new($valueLen)
                           $marshal::Copy($pValue,$b,0,$valueLen)
                           if ($b[1] -eq 0 -and $b[-1] -eq 0 -and $b[0] -ne 0) {
                                [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($b)
                           } else {
                                [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($b)}
                           }
                        4 {$marshal::ReadInt32($pValue)}
                        7 {$b = [byte[]]::new($valueLen)
                           $marshal::Copy($pValue,$b,0,$valueLen)
                           $msz = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($b)
                           $msz.TrimEnd(0).split(0)}
                       11 {$marshal::ReadInt64($pValue)}
                    }
                    # if ($name -match $global:search) {
                    #     write-host "$path\$name : $value"
                    #     $global:hits++
                    # } elseif ($value -match $global:search) {
                    #     write-host "$path\$name : $value"
                    #     $global:hits++
                    # }

                    # only find keys based on matched value data
                    if  ($value -match $global:search) {
                            write-host "$path$name : $value"
                            $item = "$path : $value"
                            $keyList.Add($item)
                            $global:hits++                           
                        }
                }
            }
            $marshal::FreeHGlobal($pName)
            $marshal::FreeHGlobal($pValue)
        }

        # enumerate the subkeys:
        if ($subkeyCount -gt 0) {
            $subKeyList = @()
            $pName = $marshal::AllocHGlobal($maxSubkeyLen)
            $subkeyList = foreach ($index in 0..($subkeyCount-1)) {
                $nameLen = $maxSubkeyLen
                $result = $reg::RegEnumKeyEx($hkey, $index, $pName, [ref]$nameLen,0,0,0, [ref]$time)
                if ($result -eq 0) {
                    $marshal::PtrToStringUni($pName)
                }
            }
            $marshal::FreeHGlobal($pName)
        }

        # close:
        $result = $reg::RegCloseKey($hkey)

        # get Tree-Size from each subkey:
        $subKeyValueCount = 0
        if ($subkeyCount -gt 0) {
            foreach ($subkey in $subkeyList) {
                if (!($subkey.EndsWith("\"))){
                    $subKeyValueCount += search-RegistryTree "$path$subkey\"
                }
                else{
                    $subKeyValueCount += search-RegistryTree "$path$subkey"
                }
            }
        }
        return ($valueCount+$subKeyValueCount)
    }
}
function remove-keys ($keyList){

    Write-Output "The following KEYS will be removed: "
    foreach ($key in $keyList){
        $value = $key.split(":")[1]
        $key = $key.split(":")[0].TrimEnd()
        Get-Item -Path "$root\$key" 
       
    }
    foreach ($key in $keyList){
        $value = $key.split(":")[1]
        $key = $key.split(":")[0].TrimEnd()
        # Get-Item -Path "$root\$key" 
        Remove-Item -Path "$root\$key"  -Recurse -WhatIf
    }

}

$timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()
$timer.Start()


# setting global variables:
$search = "test123"

#needs to change depending on the location you are searching
# $hive   = [uint32]"0x80000002" #HKLM
$hive   = [uint32]"0x80000000" #HKCR

# $root = "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
$root = "REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"

# to search from the root level of the hive you selected
$subkey = ""
# $subkey = "CLSID"
$time   = New-Object System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
$hits   = 0
$keyList =   [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

write-host "We start searching for pattern '$search' in Registry-Path '$subkey' ...`n"
$count = search-RegistryTree $subkey
Write-Output $values
$timer.stop()
$sec = [int](100 * $timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)/100
write-host "`nWe checked $count reg-values in $sec seconds. Number of hits = $hits."

remove-keys $keyList
```

In both solutions you'll need to remove `-whatIf` when using `remove-item` to actually remove the item. I just left it here for safety. It'll remove the key and any subkeys of that key if there is a match. I'd recommend testing with your search term first before removing `-whatIf` to make sure it matching with what you want to remove.